# How to set a timer with a Vue.js class

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

im just using Vue.js to updates posts on a site im messing around with, this is what ive got so far (im still learning javascript, and not too great at it)

**[app.js]**

```
var Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

var app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  components: {
    'postlist' : require('./components/postlist/postlist.js')
  }

});
```

**[postlist.js]**

```
module.exports = {

  template: require('./postlist.template.html'),

  data: function () {
    return {
      'search': '',
      'posts' : {}
    }
  },

  methods: {
    'updatePosts' : function()
    {
      this.$http.get('api/posts', function(responce, status, request)
      {
        this.$set('posts', responce.data);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

What I'm looking for is to have updatePosts fire off every x seconds, how do I do this?

ive tried doing this in the **app.js**

```
setInterval(function()
{
  app.components.postlist.methods.updatePosts(); // doesnt work
  app.postlist.updatePosts(); //doesnt work either
}, 500);
```

and tried putting the setInterval into the component itself

im pretty lost with this, whats the best way to achieve this?

updatePosts running every x seconds?

Comment: If you meant to have the `updatePosts` method called every 5 seconds you should change 500 to 5000ms. And put an alert or `console.log` to see if the `setInterval` is called every x milli-seconds.

Answer (score 7):

I have also trouble with scopes in Vue.

this should work

```
module.exports = {
  template: require('./postlist.template.html'),
  data: function () {
    return {
      'search': '',
      posts: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updatePosts: function () {
      var self = this;
      self.$http.get('api/posts', function(responce, status, request) {
        self.posts = responce.data;
        setTimeout(function(){ self.updatePosts() }, 2000);
      });
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.updatePosts();
  }
}
```

Functions in Vue works kinda different way, because your method `updatePosts` is not regular function. It is function defined in `$vm.methods` object. so It can't be called regularly like `setTimeout($vm.updatePosts)`. Actually `$vm.updatePosts` doesn't exists.   if you called it like `$vm.updatePosts()` it is different story.  `$vm` instance automatically calls   its method...    So correct way is `setTimeout(function(){ self.updatePosts()  },2000)`

Answer (score 5):

You could start the request cycle in [`created`](http://vuejs.org/api/options.html#created) or somewhere else in the lifecycle. It's also probably better to use recursion here so you can wait for the response to come back before you send off another one. I didn't test this code fully but it should work.

```
module.exports = {
  template: require('./postlist.template.html'),
  data: function () {
    return {
      'search': '',
      posts: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updatePosts: function () {
      this.$http.get('api/posts', function(responce, status, request) {
        this.posts = responce.data;
        setTimeout(this.updatePosts, 2000);
      });
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.updatePosts();
  }
}
```

Comment: it works kinda different way, because your method `updatePosts` is not regular function. It is function defined in `$vm.methods` object. so It can't be called regularly like `setTimeout($vm.updatePosts)`. Actually `$vm.updatePosts` doesn't exists.   if you called it like `$vm.updatePosts()` it is different story.  `$vm` instance automatically calls   its method...    So correct way is `setTimeout(function(){ self.updatePosts()  },2000)`

Comment: There's no difference between `setTimeout(function() { self.updatePosts() }, 2000)` and `setTimeout(self.updatePosts, 2000)`.

Comment: In fact this answer can be updated. No need for `var self = this` anymore. I'm going to do that.